# Snakemake copy from several directories

Tags: snakemake

Snakemake is super-confusing to me. I have files of the form:

```
indir/type/name_1/run_1/name_1_processed.out
indir/type/name_1/run_2/name_1_processed.out
indir/type/name_2/run_1/name_2_processed.out
indir/type/name_2/run_2/name_2_processed.out
```

where `type`, `name`, and the numbers are variable. I would like to aggregate files such that all files with the same "name" end up in a single dir:

```
outdir/type/name/name_1-1.out
outdir/type/name/name_1-2.out
outdir/type/name/name_2-1.out
outdir/type/name/name_2-2.out
```

How do I write a snakemake rule to do this? I first tried the following

```
rule rename:
    input:
        "indir/{type}/{name}_{nameno}/run_{runno}/{name}_{nameno}_processed.out"
    output:
        "outdir/{type}/{name}/{name}_{nameno}-{runno}.out"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"

# example command: snakemake --cores 1 outdir/type/name/name_1-1.out
```

This worked, but doing it this way doesn't save me any effort because I have to know what the output files are ahead of time, so basically I'd have to pass all the output files as a list of arguments to `snakemake`, requiring a bit of shell trickery to get the variables.

So then I tried to use `directory` (as well as give up on preserving `runno`).

```
rule rename2:
    input:
        "indir/{type}/{name}_{nameno}"
    output:
        directory("outdir/{type}/{name}")
    shell:
        """
        for d in {input}/run_*; do
          i=0
          for f in ${{d}}/*processed.out; do
            cp ${{f}} {output}/{wildcards.name}_{wildcards.nameno}-${{i}}.out
          done
          let ++i
        done
        """
```

This gave me the error, `Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files: 'nameno'`. I get it; `{nameno}` doesn't exist in `output`. But I don't want it there in the directory name, only in the filename that gets copied.

Also, if I delete `{nameno}`, then it complains because it can't find the right input file.

What are the best practices here for what I'm trying to do? Also, how does one wrap their head around the fact that in snakemake, you specify outputs, not inputs? I think this latter fact is what is so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is the `expand` function:

```
rule all:
    input: expand("outdir/{type}/{name}/{name}_{nameno}-{runno}.out",
                  type=TYPES,
                  name=NAMES,
                  nameno=NAME_NUMBERS,
                  runno=RUN_NUMBERS)
```

The `TYPES`, `NAMES`, `NAME_NUMBERS` and `RUN_NUMBERS` are the lists of all possible values for these parameters. You either need to hardcode or use the `glob_wildcards` function to collects these data:

```
TYPES, NAMES, NAME_NUMBERS, RUN_NUMBERS, = glob_wildcards("indir/{type}/{name}_{nameno}/run_{runno}/{name}_{nameno}_processed.out")
```

This however would give you duplicates. If that is not desireble, remove the duplicates:

```
TYPES, NAMES, NAME_NUMBERS, RUN_NUMBERS, = map(set, glob_wildcards("indir/{type}/{name}_{nameno}/run_{runno}/{name}_{nameno}_processed.out"))
```

Comment: I see, overall I was assuming Snakemake could figure more things out than is possible.